# Programmatically Pressing a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, sendkeys, object-tag

I've been trying to automate the website by inputting the
Username and password, inputting the Username is fine because it's just an input tag, but the password is an object tag and SendKeys doesn't work. It's only working when i actually pressing the key directly from my keyboard.

My question is, Is there anyway to programmatically press a keyboard without using a SendKeys in any programming language?

Sorry for my bad english. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for testing purposes? There are UI testing tools out there like selenium.

Comment: Yes sir. I already embed the selenium lib to my c# project
but it's still doesn't work. Also, there is a delay on every character when inputting using selenium.

Comment: ok sorry, I only know of Selenium, never actually used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Selenium for this.

EG.

```
<html>
.
.
<input type="password">
.
.
</html>
```

you would use something like (assuming the password field is the only one on the page):-

```
WebElement passwordElement = seleniumDriver.FindElement(By.xpath("\\input[@type='password']"));
passwordElement.Clear();
passwordElement.SendKeys(password);
```

Comment: Hi sir,

It's not just a input tag, it's an object sir.. Selenium doesn't work either
on this.

Comment: If this is an embedded object, rather than HTML, then a more bespoke approach is needed.  Selenium allows for Javascript injection into the DOM and so this is probably the way forward, depending onwhat the object actually is.